# Xamarin Android ImageView not showing

Tags: android, xamarin, imageview

As in the title, image is not showing up neither in designer nor in runtime. The image is a random one 82x53 pixels, 629 B, created in Paint and saved as png. Clearing and rebuilding solution doesn't fix the issue.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/test_image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/test"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Widget;

namespace Lab01
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            var imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.test_image);
            imageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.test);
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

[Solution explorer screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhbb5.png)

[Running application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiOHK.png)

[test.png image properties tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVaZA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Android LinearLayout xml attribute [android:orientation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout#attr_android:orientation):

> Should the layout be a column or a row? Use "horizontal" for a row, "vertical" for a column. The default is horizontal.

When you don't specify LinearLayout's android:orientation attribute, it's set to "horizontal" by default, with your TextView width set to 'match_parent', your ImageView will be out of screen

To make your ImageView show under the TextView, you can add this attribute to LinearLayout:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

or change your TextView with:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a background color to verify if imageview is rendering in the layout. Also there is no need to set ImageResource again in OnCreate method.